# Css to emulate scaling in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

There is a print setting (Scale) in Chrome that I would like to emulate.

[image]

In IE11, I have added in the css and that seems to fix it but not in Chrome.

```
@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 1mm 1mm 0 5mm;
}
```

In Chrome, I have to manually change the scale to 50 to fix it. I have tried in css

```
zoom: 50%
transform: scale(0.5);
```

**UPDATE**
Now I know why it is working in IE11. Nothing to do with setting the A4 size.
Looks like IE has a 'Shrink to Fit' settings that's turned on by default.
I don't think there is a way to do in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

It is because of the bootstrap css.

I implemented the fix below and it seems to work for now.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12078

Comment: but I thought you want to use Chrome’s Scale feature

Comment: Chrome scale feature is a workaround but i found the solution.

Comment: But the way asked it seemed you want to achieve ``scale`` only. Anyways.

Comment: Yes initially until I found the solution. That is a workaround. Using zoom/scale in css wont fix the bootstrap issue. It has different behaviour to the scale setting in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide zoom in `@page`. However you can set `zoom` to parent container inside `@media print`. You can do something like this

```
@media print: {
    .container: {
      zoom: 50%;
    }
}
```

Here `container` class is applied to parent, so when you print it entire screen will be scaled to `50%`.

As per documentation `@page` only support `size, marks and bleed`. More details available over here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page.

For more details about using print css you can read beautiful blog by Racheal Andrew. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

You can check pen here https://codepen.io/sandipnirmal/pen/ajWWgp.

Following are screenshots:

**Chrome Scaling:**

[image: Chrome print view scaled to 50]

**Media Print with zoom: 50%**

[image: Zoom level set to 50% for media query]

Comment: Does not work. When you zoom the control zoom out as it is, different to what the scale property is doing in chrome.

Comment: @ove I updated the answer to use ``scale`` instead of zoom. You can check the codepen example. I think it should help you.

Comment: Have you checked the codepen? Can you add your example code/page structure?

Comment: Yes, I changed the scale value in your pen and nothing happens on Chrome

Comment: @ove can you use ``zoom: 50%`` instead of ``transform: scale(0.5)`` and remove ``transform-origin``. I made changes to the original answer. Also modified pen. It is working perfectly for me. You can give it a try.

Comment: @ove Actually, I was using ``zoom`` earlier then switched to ``scale`` not sure why, but ``zoom`` seems to work just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176696/discussion-between-sandip-nirmal-and-ove).

Answer (score 0):

Those are User settings you are trying to manipulate and you cannot alter the Scale.
Try this out:

```
@media print {
body {transform: scale(.5);}
table {page-break-inside: avoid;}
```

}

Comment: Try the same thing, but instead of body, use html