# CSS to emulate print scaling in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, puppeteer

I have a large number of template files I am printing with Chromium. They all rely on the same CSS file. On a good number of them I need to just make everything a little smaller. If I adjust the scale in Chromes print options to 75% I get the desired result.

I need a way to get a similar result in CSS?

The only browser compatibility I need is Chrome.

This question was asked before, but wasn't really answered as the person asking the question was only using this as a workaround and found a better solution to the problem. In my case I really want to know the answer to the asked question.

[Css to emulate scaling in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396225/css-to-emulate-scaling-in-chrome)

I have tried all the suggestions proposed in this post and none of them worked.

Comment: Does `body { zoom: 75%; }` not work for you?

Comment: No, It zooms the entire page. I'm wondering If I can get something similar to how the scale works in the Chrome print settings.